# Getting error while using GroupBy and Pagination in Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, pagination, eloquent

I'm trying to use eloquent to get me a grouped by response and at the same time give me a Pagination response (The one that gives me the link to the second page).
I'm trying to do this:

```
App\Eating::Where('student_id', 2)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->groupBy(function ($row) {
     return Carbon\Carbon::parse($row->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
})->paginate(25);
```

But, I'm getting this error when running it in the Tinker:

```
PHP warning:  strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in D:\Folder\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php on line 58
```

without the groupBy, I'm getting the correct result:

```
>>> App\Eating::Where('student_id', 2)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(25)->toArray();
=> [
     "total" => 1,
     "per_page" => 25,
     "current_page" => 1,
     "last_page" => 1,
     "next_page_url" => null,
     "prev_page_url" => null,
     "from" => 1,
     "to" => 3,
     "data" => [
       [
         "id" => 5,
         "status" => "Comeu Bem",
         "created_at" => "2017-07-05 13:55:25",
         "updated_at" => "2017-07-05 13:55:25",
       ],
     ],
   ]
```

BUT, when I remove the pagination, I do get the error but only because I added the get():

```
>>>  App\Eating::Where('student_id', 2)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->groupBy(function ($row) {
...                          return Carbon\Carbon::parse($row->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
...                      })->get();
PHP warning:  strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in D:\Joao\git\F1Softwares\Code\Server\F1Softwares\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php on line 58
>>>
>>>  
>>>  App\Eating::Where('student_id', 2)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->groupBy(function ($row) {
...                          return Carbon\Carbon::parse($row->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
...                      });
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#855}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? I do need to have the orderBy AND the pagination, to make it easier for the app to show the results(It is a RestFul call).

Thanks,
João

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call the `groupBy()` method on a collection, but it seems this won't work with `paginate()`. You could try using the [`forPage()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-forpage) method on the collection:

```
App\Eating::where('student_id', 2)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get()->groupBy(function ($eating) {
         return $eating->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
    })->forPage(1, 25);
```

Also, just a note, you don't need to use Carbon to parse the date, Eloquent does this for you.

---

Alternatively, you could try to [manually create your paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) once you have the collection grouped using `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`.

```
$eatings = App\Eating::where('student_id', 2)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
               ->get()->groupBy(function ($eating) {
                   return $eating->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
               });
$paginatedEatings = new LengthAwarePaginator($eatings, $eatings->count(), 25);

return $paginatedEatings->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
The problem with that I that I lost the result of the pagination then. 
I do need the next_page_link, but using this approach, I got the data grouped, but no pagination. Result:
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#891
     all: [
       "2017-07-05" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#909
         all: [
           App\Eating {#945
             id: 5,
             status: "Comeu Bem",
             created_at: "2017-07-05 13:55:25",
           },
         ],
       },

Comment: Ah I see now how it didn't paginate... after reading the docs though it appears you can't use the two together: "Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually." https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination